# How to recognize different HID keyboards in WPF

Tags: c#, input

I'm developing WPF application. I have two textboxes in XAML, I now want the two textboxes to receive input message from different HID keyboards which has different PID and VID. How to achieve it?

Comment: 1. https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/hid/hclient (C++) 2. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1244702/How-to-Communicate-with-its-USB-Devices-using-HID (C#)

Comment: I know how to read data from HID keyboards. The question is when the textbox got focused, it will show the input message from the non-target HID keyboard.